# How to do a query for multiple categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 simple models

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :course
end

class Course < ApplicationRecord  
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :tags
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :tags
end
```

Given a category as a **string** (for example 'Japanese') it's trivial to find courses by `Category.find_by_title('Japanese').courses`

I'm having a hard time doing a query if categories are in an **array**, for example ['Japanese', 'Language'] which needs to return courses tagged as 'Japanese' *and* 'Language'

Answer (score 0):

You can query by using joins:

```rb
Course.joins(categories: :tags).where(categories: {title: ['array condition']}, tags: {tag: ['array condition']})
```

Comment: I think this query returns courses that are tagged 'Japanese' **or** 'Language'. We need the query to return courses that are tagged 'Japanese' **and** 'Language'

Comment: Oops, my bad, I have edited my ans, plz check if it works

Comment: I wasn't sure what 'array condition', but this query didn't work for me `Course.joins(categories: :tags).where(categories: {title: ['Japanese', 'Language']}, tags: {tag: ['Japanese', 'Language']})`

Comment: In this case, it is what information you want to query, for example, is `['Japanese', 'Language']`, what do you can get after running this query, empty result or error, have you check your data is correct, is the column to check with the Tag is correct, I have just give assumption Tag column name is `tag` but I'm not sure in your table it's correct or not